# OpenCV _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK error. C++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I have a strange issue with my OpenCV application.
I've written a function which task is to compute position of the biggest red object on camera screen. Everything works fine, but if i put something bigger in front of the camera, something that takes 40% of screen area, the app crashes with  _CRT_DEBUGGER_HOOK error according to VS2015.
I'am using opencv x64 libraries, and x64 built boost asio libraries for transffering data between applications.

Here is code of problematic function:

```
Result * ImageProcessor::processImage(Mat &mat) {

    Scalar min(config.FROM_VALUE_RANGE, config.FROM_SATURATION_RANGE, config.FROM_HUE_RANGE);
    Scalar max(config.TO_VALUE_RANGE, config.TO_SATURATION_RANGE, config.TO_HUE_RANGE);

    Mat treshHold(config.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, config.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);
    Mat erodeKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(config.ERODE_KERNEL_CIRCLE_SIZE, config.ERODE_KERNEL_CIRCLE_SIZE));
    Mat dilateKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(config.DILATE_KERNEL_CIRCLE_SIZE, config.DILATE_KERNEL_CIRCLE_SIZE));

    cvtColor(mat, treshHold, COLOR_RGB2HSV);
    inRange(treshHold, min, max, treshHold);
    erode(treshHold, treshHold, erodeKernel);
    dilate(treshHold, treshHold, dilateKernel);
    medianBlur(treshHold, treshHold, config.MEDIAN_BLUR);

    if (countNonZero(treshHold) < config.MIN_ON_PIXELS) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Canny(treshHold, treshHold, 0, 1);
    findContours(treshHold, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    vector<Point> biggestVec = vector<Point>();
    for (vector<Point> vec : contours) {
        if (vec.size() > biggestVec.size()) {
            biggestVec = vec;
        }
    }

    if (config.SHOW) {
        drawContours(treshHold, contours, 0, config.WHITE_SCALAR, 2);
    }

    if (biggestVec.size() == 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Rect rect = boundingRect(biggestVec);
    Point center = Point(rect.x + rect.height / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);

    addPointToList(center);

    if (config.SHOW) {
        int size = pointList.size();
        if (size >= 2) {

            std::list<Point>::iterator firstIter = pointList.begin();
            std::list<Point>::iterator secondIter = pointList.begin();

            std::advance(firstIter, size - 2);
            std::advance(secondIter, size - 1);
            drawVector(treshHold, *firstIter, *secondIter);
        }
        circle(treshHold, center, 0, config.WHITE_SCALAR);
        circle(treshHold, center, rect.height / 2, config.WHITE_SCALAR);

        String img_pos = "IMG_POS : " + to_string(center.x) + ", " + to_string(center.y);
        String real_pos = "REAL_POS : " + to_string((center.x * (config.RATIO))) + ", " + to_string((center.y * (config.RATIO)));

        putText(treshHold, img_pos, Point(0, 40), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.3, config.WHITE_SCALAR);
        putText(treshHold, real_pos, Point(0, 20), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.3, config.WHITE_SCALAR);
    }

    if (config.SHOW) {
        imshow("Before", mat);
        imshow("After", treshHold);
    }

    if (pointList.size() < 2) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return new Result(pointList, config);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
After disabling VS2015 optimization, program exits with code -1073740777.
While debugging (optimization on and off) i noticed that program crashes while returning from given function.

Comment: And the `exact` exception?

Comment: I found "Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000026C318." only.